# pydrake- Error when connecting IiwaCommandSender to LcmPublisherSystem

Tags: drake

I have the following lines in my program-

```
lcm = DrakeLcm() 

lcm_command_sender = builder.AddSystem(IiwaCommandSender())

lcm_publisher = builder.AddSystem(LcmPublisherSystem.Make(channel="IIWA_COMMAND", lcm_type=lcmt_iiwa_command, lcm=lcm, publish_period=0.01))

//Connect controller to command sender
builder.Connect(controller.GetOutputPort("joint_positions"), lcm_command_sender.get_position_input_port())

//Connect lcm command sender to publisher
builder.Connect(lcm_command_sender.GetOutputPort("lcmt_iiwa_command"), lcm_publisher.get_input_port())
```

Upon running, the last line gives the following runtime error-

```
RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Mismatched value types while connecting output port lcmt_iiwa_command of System lcm_command_sender (type drake::lcmt_iiwa_command) to input port lcm_message of System LcmPublisherSystem(IIWA_COMMAND) (type drake::pydrake::Object)
```

I am not sure why this happens, since the documentation specifically says that the output port of `IiwaCommandSender` should be connected to the input port of `LcmPublisherSystem`, and both of them are of the type `AbstractValue`. What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, the output port of the IiwaCommandSender is of type "drake::lcmt_iiwa_command" (a C++ class wrapped in Python), but the input port of the LcmPublisherSystem is of type "drake.lcmt_iiwa_command" (a Python class).  Those are two different runtime types, even though they both represent an LCM message.

In this case, you should set `use_cpp_serializer=True` when calling `LcmPublisherSystem.Make` so that the input port is the C++ type, instead of the Python type.

https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.lcm.html#pydrake.systems.lcm.LcmPublisherSystem.Make